# How can I make Laravel/Lumen print console friendly exceptions instead of HTML?

Tags: laravel, exception, testing, console, lumen

I'm using TDD to develop an API in Lumen. This means that I'm running PHPUnit in my console a lot and often getting exceptions. These are decorated with a bunch of HTML which obviously isn't very readable in the console. Is there a way to get Lumen to print console friendly exceptions when the app is run from the console?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/adamwathan/125847c7e3f16b88fa33a9f8b42333da

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi Thanks a lot! That was totally what I was looking for. I ended up just adding the following conditional in the exception handler render function
`if (\php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    throw $e;
} else {
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}`
although I'm not sure that also fixes the issues with errors being hidden by the exception handler that is mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this modified code from this [`link`](http://%09%20gist.github.com/adamwathan/125847c7e3f16b88fa33a9f8b42333da).

This was a bug on Laravel not sure for lumen. As on Laravel 5.5, the methods `withExceptionHandling()` and `withoutExceptionHandling()` are coming out of the box. So no need to use the above solution